# Android multi-line notification with small icon

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

When we use 'BigTextStyle' to notify multi-line message, a small icon appears in the line of summary text.
Without using summary, small icon is never shown in the notification and once the area has been swiped, the icon appears.

If a message to notify is long or multi-line text, the behavior seem to be natural. However, if a message notified is short, I seem to be strange because  notification bar is not expanded and only the icon appeared.

I want to apply 'BigTextStyle' to a notification because sent message is not clear if it will be long or short. Does anyone know the best way to let the behavior of the icon behave naturally ?